# Python / networkx: creation of note attributes fails erratically

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx

I see an effect which drives me crazy and which I do not understand:
I am fetching data from a 6 column SQL Server 2012 database table (nodeID, string(Class), float(xCoordinate), float(ycoordinate), stringZone, char(Reference)) and I want to create a network graph of these entities using the networkx Python package. Important to me is that I do have a couple of network nodes with pre-defined coordinates, which I want to keep fixed laterone, where the rest will be layouted using Gephi.

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import networkx as nx

dbConnection = pyodbc.connect('DB-Connection String')
dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()

theGraph = nx.Graph()
theGraph.position={}
theGraph.deviceClass={}

queryStatement = "SELECT ComponentID, DeviceClass, CoordX, CoordY, AcceleratorZone, Reference FROM dbo.vComponentsWithZones WHERE Reference IN ('M','T')"
for dbRow in dbCursor.execute(queryStatement):
    nodeID = dbRow[0]
    theGraph.add_node(nodeID)

    deviceClass = dbRow[1]
    coordX = (dbRow[2] - 367421.373) / 100
    coordY = (dbRow[3] - 230238.784) / 100
    accelZone = dbRow[4]

    if coordX != None and coordY != None:
        print nodeID, coordX, coordY   <-------------------------
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'position': {'x': coordX, 'y': coordY, 'z': 0}}

    if accelZone != None:
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["AccelZone"] = accelZone
    if dbRow[1] != None:
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["DeviceClass"] = deviceClass 

    if deviceClass == "Controls":
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'color': {'r': "255", 'g': "0", 'b': "0", 'a': "1"}}
    elif deviceClass == "Magnet":
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'color': {'r': "255", 'g': "200", 'b': "0", 'a': "1"}}
    elif deviceClass == "Vacuum":
        theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'color': {'r': "0", 'g': "0", 'b': "255", 'a': "1"}}

queryStatement = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ComponentConnections"
for dbRow in dbCursor.execute(queryStatement):
    theGraph.add_edge(dbRow[0],dbRow[1], connectionTyp=dbRow[2])

dbConnection.close()

nx.write_gexf(theGraph,"cryringTopology.gexf")
```

Everything seems to work fine, looking at the output of the print statement, things seems to work well too; I do get values for nodeID, coordX, coordY wherever is an entry in the database and the program evaluates the statement

```
if coordX != None and coordY != None:
```

true and executes the code therein correctly.

[Screenshot of print output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNbtV.png)

However, the output to the GEXF-file produces only for 6 of the entries correctly assigned coordinates, where it should be something like 40 - 50. It seems that the creation of the "position" node attributes fails in some cases, I am completely lost.

Any ideas???

Comment: Change `theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'color': {'r': "255", 'g': "0", 'b': "0", 'a': "1"}}` to `theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"]['color']= {'r': "255", 'g': "0", 'b': "0", 'a': "1"}` (and similar for the other 'color' lines).  Stefan's answer explains why this change will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you store in this line

```
theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'position': {'x': coordX, 'y': coordY, 'z': 0}}
```

is overwritten by these lines

```
theGraph.node[nodeID]["viz"] = {'color': {'r': "255", 'g': "0", 'b': "0", 'a': "1"}}
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't help fix the problem. I would suggest instead of doing the second assignment, update the dictionary.

Comment: In addition to what bourbaki said - another choice would be to use something other than `["viz"]` for the color.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, your answer helped me to realize that I overwrite my attributes.
@bourbaki4481472: could you be so kind and give an explicit example how to update the dictionary?

Comment: @WolfiG  See my comment directly to your question.

Comment: @WolfiG Example: `d = {'some_key' : 'some_value'}` and `h = {'other_key' : 'other_value'}`. In order to merge two dictionaries, do `d.update(h)`